# Sidebar does not open on click

Tags: javascript

I'm not understanding why the sidebar doesn't open on click, it stays open all the time.

Where is the mistake?

```js
function openSidebar() {
    let sidebar = document.querySelector('#sidebarmusic');
    sidebar.classList.toggle('open');
}


sidebarToggler.addEventListener('click', openSidebar);
```

```css
#sidebarmusic{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100vh;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: var(--black);
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#sidebarmusic.open{
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebarmusic">
    </div>

    <div class="container-music">
        <div class="header tx-main px-4 py-2 d-flex align-items-center">
            <span id="sidebar-toggler" class="tx-gradient"><i class="fa-solid fa-music"></i>Playlist</span>
        </div>

        <div class="image d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <img id="cover-track" src="./img_music/cover-9.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things, you didn't specify the element to be toggled in your example. Also I'd suggest using `transform` instead of changing the `left` attribute to avoid a re-paint and allow a smoother transition. See example below.

```js
const sidebarToggler = document.getElementById('sidebar-toggler'),
      sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebarmusic');

sidebarToggler.addEventListener('click', openSidebar);

function openSidebar(e) {
    sidebar.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
#sidebarmusic{
    width: 300px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    background-color: var(--black);
    transition: transform 0.75s ease;
    background-color: #0f0;
}

#sidebarmusic.open{
    transform: translateX(0);
}

#sidebar-toggler {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#sidebar-toggler:hover {
  color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebarmusic">
    </div>

    <div class="container-music">
        <div class="header tx-main px-4 py-2 d-flex align-items-center">
            <span id="sidebar-toggler" class="tx-gradient"><i class="fa-solid fa-music"></i>Playlist</span>
        </div>

        <div class="image d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <img id="cover-track" src="./img_music/cover-9.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally when u have a  `sidebar.classList.toggle('open');` anything with toggle you dont specify the state it should toggle to or from but instead count on the fact that there are only 2 states and that the state should change.

so use something like  `sidebar.classList.toggle();`

Comment: it doesn't work all the same